# In Chronicle, What was the field Andrew went to after his argument with Matt, and what is he doing there?

Tags: chronicle

After Matt questions Andrew's involvment with “The Lightning Strike”, Andrew gets angry and flies off. We see him apologizing to Steve’s photo, and then we see him walking to a field with strange markings on the ground and a weird humming noise. They give NO explanation or context as to what is happening in this field scene and it left me totally confused.

What is Andrew doing there?
Was there a physical fight between him and Steve?
What are those strange markings in the grass?

Comment: Do you have a link to the scene, or maybe some screenshots?

Comment: https://youtu.be/DlJ_oWpbR04                The scene begins around 1 hour and 30 seconds into the movie